# Перенос строки после вывода значения переменной (PHPSTORM)

Tags: php

Хочу начать изучать PHP. Но на первом же уроке застрял. Во всех видео уроках, после вывода значения переменной в броузере, каждое значение выводится с новой строки. Никаких переносов в коде нет. Просто "Enter".

У меня все выводится в одной строке, и даже принудительный перенос строки PHP_EOL выводит лишь пробел.

```
<?php

$a = 1;

echo $a.PHP_EOL;
echo $a;
echo $a;
echo $a;
echo $a;

?>
```

И вывод: 1 1111

Спасибо всем заранее.

Comment: Перенос строки в браузере это тег `<br />` как минимум.

Comment: Попробуйте установить заголовок в самом начале - `header('Content-Type:text/plain');` , который прямо укажет как выводить содержимое. Либо воспользуйтесь стилизацией и укажите `white-space: pre-wrap`

Comment: Попробовал оба, к сожалению не прокатило :(

Answer (score 5):

Если вы откроете исходный код страницы, то увидите такое

```
1
1111
```

Т.е. вывелось первое значение, потом был добавлен `PHP_EOL`, а потом четыре последовательных вывода.

Но html игнорирует переводы строк и заменяет их на пробелы.

Чтобы отобразить в html данные на разных строках, нужно использовать специальные теги.

Например:

1. Каждый вывод дополнять тегом `<br/>`

   ```php
   echo $a . '<br/>';
   echo $a . '<br/>';
   ```
2. Каждый вывод дополнять `PHP_EOL`, а все выводить в тег `<pre>`

   ```php
   echo '<pre>';
   echo $a . PHP_EOL;
   echo $a . PHP_EOL;
   echo '</pre>';
   ```
3. Выводить каждую строку в отдельный блочный элемент

   ```php
   echo '<div>' . $a . '</div>';
   echo '<div>' . $a . '</div>';
   ```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, с первым вариантом разобрался, все верно. Но вопрос в том, что в уроках, которые я смотрю, каждое значение само собой выводится с новой строки, просто при переносе Enter-ом в коде.

То есть не надо заморачиваться с br. Во всех видео достаточно перенести строку в коде, что бы значения переменных вывелись каждая с новой строки.

Comment: @AlexKhakhanoff возможно результат смотрят не в браузере

Comment: @AlexKhakhanoff Если мой ответ решил вашу задачу, отметьте его как верный